# MPV accidently got no sound problem

Tags: sound, mpv-media-player

I was enjoying watching videos through `MPV` media player without any issue till yesterday.
But Today, I played a video and I found that `mpv` is **NOT** able to play audio. I can only see video, but no audio.
I don't know what happened. Given below is the output of `mpv welcome.mp4` for your reference.

[image]

#### My system info :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a new file `mpv.conf` in `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`.

```
# ===== Audio =====
ao=alsa
audio-device=auto
```

It is now working perfectly.